# Why .save files are being generated in /etc/sources.list.d/ directory?

Tags: apt

Sometimes `*.save` files are being generated in `/etc/sources.list.d/` directory and that causes error messages while using `apt-get`.

I wonder what causes being them generated. Is there any way to prevent them generated?

Example output error:

```
N: Ignoring file 'plesk.list.ai_back' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Comment: Are you using `nano` to edit these files?

Comment: i don't edit anything. they just randomly appear.

Comment: Is this a local system or a remote one? did you add any PPA and do you have any file in `/etc/sources.list.d/` ?

Comment: .save files won't cause any problems with apt-get. The only time that there's a problem is when you get something like .save.1. They're created as backups to .list files. It's normal.

Comment: @Ravexina It's a local system. My own computer.

Comment: @heynnema they just causes warning messages which is quite annoying.

Comment: If you give me an example of the errors that you're seeing, I can help you. Please edit your question to include examples. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema added

Comment: Thanks! Now it begins to make some sense. Edit your question again to include the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plesk.list.ai_back` and `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plesk*`  and I'll take a look. This error is occurring because it's not a valid filename to be in that directory. Only .list and .save filenames should appear here.

Answer (score 9):

#### Intro

`*.save` files are some kind of backup from your sources file these are not going to make any trouble, cause apt ignore these files silently.

`nano` uses similar files too, if you get a file named `*.save.1` it's because of `nano`, These are emergency files, when `nano` receives a `SIGHUB` or `SIGTERM` it will write its buffer to an emergency file to save you from data lost. For example if Terminal get closed while you have an open file or ssh connection fails (from `man nano` notes section).

`plesk.list.ai_back` is plesk backup file.

apt ignores all except `*.list` files . it show you some warning to let you know about these files however it also ignore some of them silently like `*.save` or `*.bak` files.

#### Take care of error:

As I said these are backup files, they have no impact on `apt` and are not harmful so it's the best to keep them instead of removing them.

What I suggest is using `Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently` option to add `*.ai_back` files to silently ignored list. what will happen is `apt` ignore these as before however it's not going to show you any warning anymore.

Create a file withing : `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20-ignorebk
```

Add `Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\.ai_back$";` to this file and save it.

Now you shouldn't get any warning about this kind files.

Comment: I'm not sure that your "Take care of error" is the correct solution. Why make an exception for a file that's probably not supposed to be there in the first place? I had asked the poster to show me an `ls` and a `cat` so I could see what was there, but haven't heard back. I suspect my solution might end up being to just delete that file...

Comment: `apt` by default ignore all of these files, they don't have any impact on `apt`. either apt ignore these silently or it will show you an warning. Why did I suggest to add this format to "Ignore Silently"? cause I think after removal they will be populated again. these files are not harmful and in my opinion we should keep them, why? cause they're back up files :-)

Comment: Until the user answers my request for a `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plesk.list.ai_back` and `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plesk*` I can't tell for sure that it's a backup of `plesk.list`. I've never seen a `.ai_back` file and it certainly doesn't belong in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Only .save and .list, and the occasional .save.1 (which is wrong and shouldn't be there either, but I also wouldn't make an exception for that file either). :-)

Comment: If you search about this file, you'll end up to the "plesk" website, yes it doesn't mean these are really a plesk source file however  keeping these files is not harmful, exactly because of their extension which will be ignored by apt anyway, we are just disabling the warning which still is a better option in my opinion.  it's just a suggestion not the best solution which could be or not ;)

Comment: I can't add that line to every .save file in folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, because they'll be regenerated.

Comment: You don't have to add that line to `.save` files you have to create a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` say `20-ignorebk` and then add that line to this `20-ignorebk` file.

Comment: I am recieving an error roughly translated as "/etc/apt/preferences.d/20-ignorebk invalid record in preferences folder, No package header". It just added an extra error line?

Comment: @Letitbe Updated the answer to fix the issue. However my answer only ignores files ending to `.ai_back`.

Comment: @Ravexina Your update stopped error for 20-ignorebk file, but not other warnings. I assumed the quoted part, `"\.ai_back$"`, is regex so i changed it a little bit. So the line should be `Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently:: "\S+\.ai_back$";`. That way it solved my problem. Please update your answer again. Thanks for sparing time.