# Discover lunches with error : tellico didnt start

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I use Kubuntu and disvover says that message when starting.Also there are that errors on console:

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ sudo apt-get update
Aynı:  1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Aynı:  2 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                          
Aynı:  3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                        
Yoksay:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                
Aynı:  5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                       
Aynı:  6 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                                              
İndir: 7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                          
Aynı:  8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                 
Aynı:  9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                              
Aynı:  10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                            
2 sn.'de 88,7 kB alındı (56,9 kB/s)                                                     
Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-bionic.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'google-chrome.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-bionic.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'opera-stable.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'rikmills-ubuntu-latte-dock-bionic.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
N: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' dizinindeki 'gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save' dosyası geçersiz bir dosya uzantısı olduğu için yok sayılıyor
ahmet@ahmet:~$
```

**Turkish sentences says the file has not avaiable file extention so it is ignored file.**

**Aynı : same
Yoksay : İgnore**

Comment: Use `LANG=C sudo apt update`. That will give you output in English.

Comment: Related: [Why .save files are being generated in /etc/sources.list.d/ directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920835/why-save-files-are-being-generated-in-etc-sources-list-d-directory)